# How to delete Office documents?

Tags: office-hub, word

I created a Word document and it has become corrupted and is unable to be opened (I think I edited it in LibreOffice).

I have tried to long-press on the tile put I only get a 'pin to start' menu. How can I delete it? If possible I would like to leave it on OneDrive but just exclude it from my phone.

Comment: How exactly you put the file on the phone? By email?<br/>How about change the tag to [tag:office-hub]?

Comment: Didn't know that office hub was the official name :) can't currently retag using the mobile site. I created the document on the phone, saved it to SkyDrive and then edited it on PC.

Comment: Over time the "recent" document will go down the list and eventually off it I think. You might be able to get it out there faster by temporarily removing it from SkyDrive and then see if you can manipulate it in some way. Other than that, it might be that due to its corruption that it somehow got stubborn. Perhaps rooting and checking with some file manager app or so might help, but for just this one change it wouldn't be worth the risk. Perhaps just opening the other files in the right order might bump it of that list...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the document's tile from the Office Hub's documents list:

1. Open the Office Hub.
2. Pan across to locations.
3. Tap OneDrive.
4. Long-tap on the document and select *delete from phone*.

To actually delete it from OneDrive, you need install and use the official OneDrive application.

Comment: Some PDF files I got by email show in my office hub but can't delete like you said. in Locations>Phone they don't appear.

Comment: That's interesting—I have opened up a lot of PDFs from my Gmail and none of them show up in the Office Hub.

Comment: But with hotmail can you? I use only hotmail.

Comment: I sent a PDF to my Hotmail and opened it. It hasn't shown up in the hub yet, not even after a reboot.